# Placing OptionMenu in a Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I got the following code for an `OptionMenu` in `tkinter` from another post on Stack Overflow:

```
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one")
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.pack()
```

Now, if I wanted to put this `OptionMenu` in a specific frame (say, `frame1`), how should I edit this? I've tried doing this:

```
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one")
w = OptionMenu(frame1, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

and this:

```
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one")
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
```

But in both cases, the program freezes and fails to load. Do you think this is an isolated issue with the code above, or is the code above fine which means it's something else with my program (which I can look over to fix)? Thank you.

Comment: If it freezes, it is likely because you are mixing `grid` and `pack` in the same frame. Please show us a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one")
w = OptionMenu(frame1, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.pack()
```

If it works it is because you are mixing `pack()` and `grid()` geometry managers.